# jQuery - jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: filter is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, json, http, jsgrid

I am using `jsGrid` with a local `json` file as the data source. I set up a local `json-server` running on port 4000 to serve the dynamic data. When I hit `http://localhost:4000/networks`, I see the json just fine. I also set up a local http server with `npm`'s `http-server` package to hit my web page. However, when I try to hit `http://localhost:8080`, I get a blank page. In the dev console, I am seeing this error: `jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: filter is not defined`. I am a bit new to `jQuery`, and not sure why this error is happening. Below is my directory structure, my `html` file, js, sample json, and the error.

`Tree:`

```
.
└── src
    ├── data
    │   └── scan.json
    ├── hosts.js
    ├── index.html
    ├── jsgrid-theme.css
    ├── jsgrid-theme.min.css
    ├── jsgrid.css
    ├── jsgrid.js
    ├── jsgrid.min.css
    ├── jsgrid.min.js
    └── style.css
```

`index.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> 
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jsgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="jsgrid-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">      
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="jsGrid"></div> 
        <script src="http://js-grid.com/js/jsgrid.min.js"></script>
        <script src="hosts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`JSON:`

```
{
  "networks": [
          {
            "id": "dc34ec44-aba0-4a9c-9ea0-cbacf48a15e4",
            "ip": "192.168.0.4",
            "mac": "8c:85:90:ae:10:24",
            "packets_received": 74,
            "packets_sent": 97,
            "data_sent": 1352,
            "data_received": 1076
          },
          {
            "id": "b367bc81-b6d0-4c10-86e0-f7394bf2489e",
            "ip": "192.168.0.7",
            "mac": "00:d0:2d:e9:ae:88"
          },
          {
            "id": "d46f11d4-e384-42b3-95d4-5eadc19b6552",
            "ip": "192.168.0.8",
            "mac": "34:93:42:06:01:4c"
          },
          {
            "id": "47da3cb0-ee30-44ad-a1c3-bbf542ffeae3",
            "ip": "17.249.121.246",
            "mac": "f8:a0:97:87:11:0e",
            "packets_received": 18,
            "packets_sent": 7,
            "data_sent": 156,
            "data_received": 256
          }
     ]
}
```

`JS:`

```
$(function() {

    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
      width: "auto",
      height: "auto",

      filtering: true,
      editing: false,
      sorting: true,
      paging: true,
      pageLoading : true,

      controller: {
        loadData: function (filter) {
            return $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:4000/networks",
                data: filter,
                dataType: "json"
            });
        }
      },

      data: filter,
      fields: [
        { name: "ip", type: "text", width: 100 },
        { name: "mac", type: "text", width: 100 },
        { name: "packets_received", type: "number", width: 20 },
        { name: "packets_sent", type: "number", width: 20 },
        { name: "data_received", type: "number", width: 20 },
        { name: "data_sent", type: "number", width: 20 },
      ]
    })  
  })
```

`Error:`

```
jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: filter is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (hosts.js:24)
    at e (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two occurrences of the line `data: filter`; you don't want those.

According to the [jsGrid documentation](http://js-grid.com/docs/#controller), the loadData method of the controller should return an array of data matching the structure you've defined in the `fields` property.